# Is there a list of “best practices” for Android UI design?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm a beginner in android development, Is there any online material which specifies best practices for UI design.
I found [Best Practices for User Interface | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/best-ui.html) online,
but i am searching for something like

- Radio buttons should be placed Xdp from margin
- Standard fonts used
- Standard text size
- TextView should be placed Xdp from margin

Is there any online material specifying these type of "best practices".
Thank you

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few resources out there for what you want. For instance, for [Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) (I Might suggest the [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/), as well). For [Metrics](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) (grid sizes, icon spacing, etc). Finally, here's a good guide for [Typography](http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-standard-styles) (fonts, spacing and sizes).

If you're interested in Material UI, [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rwal.material) is quite useful.